# Git won't clean working tree - How to Diagnose

Tags: git, tree

I have a local repo and have pulled from several remotes. I am finding that I have about 15 files which are modified. Some of them have come from a remote and others I think, though I am not sure, may have been modified prior to pulling from a remote, but never committed (or else they were modified and committed locally but then have been modified via a pull).

The problem is that I don't know how to begin to work out what has happened to these files which don't get removed when I do a git reset --hard HEAD. I've tried to commit them and then rebase the commit out as well but, the files just reappear in the working tree. So it seems that  Git just isn't going to let me get rid of them. If I compare with base I don't see any differences. I thought it may be line endings but my diff/merge prog indicates that the line endings are all the same (crlf).

So how do I go about working out why git won't let me get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Is it on Windows? If so, it can be because of file name case.

If it is not, please show `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the files are modified and not committed vs. not tracked?  Not tracked files can show up if you `git reset HEAD^` where HEAD was a commit that created the file originally.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might be pushing to your repository and thus modifying the files on disc because it's not a --bare repository. Make sure no one can access your files to rule out this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

check settings

git.exe Path

incorrect ⇒　C:\xxxx\Git\bin

correct ⇒　C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Answer (score -1):

After you do `git reset --hard HEAD`, you need to do `git checkout`

Comment: Thx vm for replying ... but sorry ... that didn't make any difference. S

Comment: Can you provide example output?